# question about 1D & 2D Fourier transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have 100 1D signals (each corresponds to a 1D array of 38684 elements). Those signals are all independent and I need to find the spectrum of each of them. In this case, I have to perform 1D Fourier transformation for each of the signal, so total 100 1D FFT. I am thinking will it be the same if I put all 100 1D signals to make a 2D array so each column corresponds to 1 signal and I perform the 2D FFT on that array.

Comment: They will not be the same. You can always try it and then look at an image of the magnitude of the 2-D FT vs. the 100 1-D FTs.

Comment: There is a relation governed by the projection slice theorem, but it's not the relation you desire. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-slice_theorem